# Generating function for the number of partitions into parts 1,2,..,m, each of which is used an odd number of times

Tags: generating-functions, integer-partitions

Write the generating function for the number of partitions of $n$ into parts $1, 2, . . . , m$ each of which is used an odd number of times.

I've gotten myself confused, could someone give me a hint please? 
I have $\prod_{k\geq 1} \frac{1+x}{1-x^k}$, but I'm unsure.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all of the elements in $[m]$ must be used. Then the coefficient of $x^n$ in 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\prod_{i=1}^{m} \frac{x^i y}{(1-x^{2i} y^2)}
\end{eqnarray*}
will be a polynomial in $y$. This polynomial will grade the number of parts in each partition. If you set $y=1$ will get the number of partitions of $n$ into an odd number of parts using all the elements of $[m]$.